# Book recommendation: adaptive optics

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations

Does anyone know any good books for [adaptive optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_optics)? It should at least include decomposition into Zernike polynomials. It is for PhD level, but any level is welcome.

Comment: Robert K. Tyson, Principles of Adaptive Optics and Michael C. Roggemann, Byron M. Welsh, Imaging through Turbulence were used during my Adaptive Optics course as main sources. They are both rather comprehensive. For PhD level I think you would rather go for conference papers or proceedings. I know that the SPIE group "Adaptive Optics Systems" from the Astronomic Telescopes + Instrumentation is rather active, I would start looking there for current work.